# "Fregarsene": is it slang or "linguaggio informale" or "linguaggio quotidiano"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, sentences

I think "fregarsene" could be translated by not to give a damn and

> Se ne frega di qualcosa

by "he doesn't give a damn about something".

Would you say that this expression is slang, informal, of daily use? In which context is it suited to use this expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This popular expression is not a dirty word but can be arrogant, so in formal situations I would use:

> Non gli interessa

> Non gli importa

I think *fregarsene* has more weight than the expressions above, so it gives more weight/arrogance/emotionality to the sentence, for example:

> Non me ne frega nulla di lui, che faccia quello che vuole!

> Non me ne frega niente del Grande Fratello, odio quel tipo di format televisivo.

It can become an insult when accompanied by a swear word:

> Non me ne frega un cazzo di te, non ti considero nemmeno.

Comment: I would add that its usage is very informal: I can't imagine a politician or so, using that utterance in a public conference, or in an official document...

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica I agree with you

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica One politician used to say “me ne frego”, though. Which is a good reason not to imitate him.